# Visual SourceSafe - Disable "Get Latest On Checkout"

Tags: .net, visual-sourcesafe, vcs-checkout, getlatest

I looked for an option to switch off "Get Latest On Checkout" in Visual SourceSafe 2005 and integrated VS2008 menus, but couldn't find one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Visual Source Safe Administration Console, then click on Tools->Options. On the general tab there is the setting *Only allow checkouts of the latest version*. Uncheck it.

Now open the Visual SourceSafe Explorer, click on Tools->Options and uncheck *Always check out the working folder version of files*.

Now you should be done.